# How to get Nash-Sutcliffe efficiency by group using hydroGOF package?

Tags: r, dplyr, hydrogof

I am trying to get NSE values grouped by a variable. I tried something similar to:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hydroGOF)

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  NSE(wt,drat)
```

Why isn't it working? It doesn't find "wt". Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I get just one value while i expect three values, one for each of the cyl subset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `summarise`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(NSE = NSE(wt, drat))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl    NSE
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4 -30.2 
2     6  -2.22
3     8 -10.2
```

The reason yours wasn't working is because `%>%` redirects the output of the previous function into the first argument of the next. So yours was the equivalent of `NSE(mtcars,wt,drat)`. And since `wt` isn't defined in the global environment, it wasn't found.